# Logback several loggers with same appender

Tags: java, logging, logback

Is that possible to get several loggers working with the same appender ?
When i create a logback.xml like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-18.18thread] %highlight(%-5level) %-30.30logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="events.A" level="trace"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></logger>
    <logger name="events.B" level="trace"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></logger>
    <root level="info"/>
</configuration>
```

But when i do:

```
    Logger loggerA = LoggerFactory.getLogger("events.A");
    Logger loggerB = LoggerFactory.getLogger("events.B");
    loggerA.trace("I am A");
    loggerB.trace("I am B");
```

It prints only "I am B".

It that a normal behaviour ? is there a way to do it ?
I know i could only use "events" logger but i will have a lot of events and i would like to be able to switch log level of each events separately.

Answer (score 0):

Having one appender with multiple loggers is not only possible but normal: in facts I usually put just one `<appender-ref ref="xyz"/>` tag inside the `<root>` tag so it is valid for *all* loggers.  Your example works fine, so check better your real config.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i really executed theis code.
And the behaviour is really the one i described before :/

Comment: Strange, I also really executed your code before answering.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the logger should be present in a `loggers` section for example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-18.18thread] %highlight(%-5level) %-30.30logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
<Loggers>
    <logger name="events.A" level="trace"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></logger>
    <logger name="events.B" level="trace"><appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/></logger>
    <root level="info"/>
</Loggers>
</configuration>
```